# Update not reflected in table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This is my action method has been defined in `Home` controller for updating row

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateISRCEntry(ABC.Models.tbl1 z, List<string> verticall,string Album, string Song)
{
    if (Session["user"] != null)
    {               
        if (verticall != null)
        {
            foreach (string s1 in verticall)
            {
                if (s1 == "Radio")
                { z.Radio = "Radio"; }
                if (s1 == "Online")
                { z.Online = "Online"; }
                if (s1 == "Mobile")
                { z.Mobile = "Mobile"; }
            }
        }

        tbl1.Service.Class1.updatetbl1(z, Album, Song);
        return RedirectToAction("Home");                
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

and below is my method has been implemented in class1 to implement updatable row

```
public static bool updatetbl1(tbl1 obj, string Album, string Song)
{
    ABC.Models.tbl1 objmain = new Models.mainISRC();

    using (ABCManagementDBEntities1 dbcontect = new ABCManagementDBEntities1())
    {
        var zz = (from z in dbcontect.tbl1 
                  where z.Album == Album && z.Song == Song select z
                 ).SingleOrDefault();
        objmain.Mood = obj.Mood;
        objmain.Online = obj.Online;
        objmain.Radio = obj.Radio;
        dbcontect.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

All these codes are running successfully but the update is not reflected in my table for that row. However, during running my code no any kind of error is arise. Please help someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this before  `dbcontect.SaveChanges();`

```
dbcontect.Entry(objmain).State = EntityState.Modified;
dbcontect.SaveChanges();
```

or I think just this will do

```
this.UpdateModel(objmain);
dbcontect.SaveChanges();
```

You should update entity before `SaveChanges()`

Answer (score 1):

Why are you pulling the zz object and never use it? The way your wrote your "updatetbl1" method, you are inserting a new object (objmain) to the database instead of updating the zz object. Am I assuming correct here?

I think it should be like this:

```
public static bool updatetbl1(tbl1 obj, string Album, string Song)
{
    ABC.Models.tbl1 objmain = new Models.mainISRC();

    using (ABCManagementDBEntities1 dbcontect = new ABCManagementDBEntities1())
    {
        var zz = (from z in dbcontect.tbl1 
              where z.Album == Album && z.Song == Song select z
             ).SingleOrDefault();
        zz.Mood = obj.Mood;
        zz.Online = obj.Online;
        zz.Radio = obj.Radio;
        dbcontect.Entry(zz).State = EntityState.Modified;
        dbcontect.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```